# Angular ivh-treeview CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, web, frontend

I,m having a CSS issue.
The image for the subchild and the child is the same.
But some how the spacing between the subchild and the " | " is less
and the spacing between the child and the " | " is more.

[image]

Solutions that could be done :

1)- if there is anyway to change css for subchild and child.
   (If you had worked previously with ivh-tree view then you would 
    know the structure is same for subchild and child so anything i apply to subchild is getting applied to child).

OR

2)- if there is a way to change image for child when it does not have a    subchild. that would work as well. Because the image changes from " | "
to " - " when there is a subchild.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this using the jsbin template from here: https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#reporting-issues-and-getting-help. It looks like the spacing is consistent with the default options.

Comment: Is there a way to change the styling of the tree....i,m trying to make something more like this : https://community.smartbear.com/nwkab66374/attachments/nwkab66374/Functional_Web_Testing/22039/2/TC_jstree_IE10.png

Comment: Sure, have you read through the template and skins doc? https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/docs/templates-and-skins.md

Comment: Thanks @jtrussell....i was able to solve this issue with CSS... :-)